# HTML5 locaStorage and ASP.Net App debugging

Tags: asp.net, html, visual-studio-2012, local-storage

I am debugging my ASP.Net app using Visual Studio 2012 (IE10) and looks like the data that I have stored onto localStorage disappears after each debug session. Here is what I am doing

Store some data to localStorage using

```
localStorage.setItem(KEY_MY_OBJECT, JSON.stringify(myObject));
```

I access them using

```
JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(KEY_MY_OBJECT))
```

The get & set works fine in the same debug session but the local storage for my key is `null` on the subsequent debug sessions (*after closing the current browser window and hitting F5 to restart a new debug session*). From my understanding of the localStorage, I was expecting the data to persist even after closing the window.

Here is how the Url looks while debugging

```
http://localhost/AppName/AppDashboardDashboard.aspx?&param1=param1value
```

Could you please let me know if I am missing something here? Or will contents of localStorage not persist across debug sessions?

Comment: It persists properly for me in IE9, with VS configured to use IIS as the web host.

Comment: I am not sure why it is not working for me. I am also using IIS (and not IIS express) as the web host

Comment: Maybe it's an IE10 thing. When developing, it sometimes would be convenient to have test data cleared although it certainly wouldn't be desirable in a production app. I guess the thing to validate is that it isn't clearing the data when the app is **not** running with the debugger attached.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like an issue with IE10 and debugging. It worked fine in release mode